# OAuth Mailchimp Popup windows closes on redirecting to login page

Tags: oauth, mailchimp, popupwindow

My project allows Mailchimp OAuth via popup window, I was able to login to Mailchimp and give permission to my OAuth app since more than a year. From 08-May-2023, i am having problem when i redirect to Mailchimp login window using Popup, Popup window closes immediately when showing Mailchimp login window. This issue happens in all browsers. Even after updating all my browsers to the latest version, still the issue occurs.

Does anybody faced this issue regarding Mailchimp? Is there a work around for these type of issues?

Regards,
Rajagopalan